# Query with multiple condition in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have some problem with this mongoid. It's my first time to use mongoDB, Before, I always use mySQL.

Here is my problem.
I have model "User". In model "User" has embedded one "Profile", 
and I want to search users data with criteria name "dummy" for field "profile.first_name", 
"profile.last_name", and "username".

I already use this syntax, but I got empty result:

```
@filter = "dummy"
@users = User.any_of({'profile.first_name' => /#{@filter}/i, 'profile.last_name' => /#{@filter}/i, :username => /#{@filter}/i})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
@filter = "dummy"
@users = User.any_of({:profile.first_name => "/@filter/i"},{:profile.last_name="/@filter/i"}, {:username => "/@filter/i"})
```

look at the brackets.

Comment: Ops... yeah.. my faults. Thank you!